# How would I Import Data Daily Into SQL Server RDS AWS from an external MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Currently I have a job on SQL Server that uses a linkedserver to our MySQL database to import data. We now have an SQL Server RDS and so I need to have the data be imported into it from the MySQL db. I can't set up a linked server within AWS from a database that is not hosted with AWS, so looking for a solution.